# Unique records on multiple columns in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, unique-constraint

I have for example 2 tables:

**Table 1: user**

```
userid
titleid (Links to title table below)
name
surname
```

**Table 2: title**

```
titleid
title
```

**User Entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user", 
       uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="user_unique", columnNames={"titleid", "name"})})
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM user e")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userid", insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long userId;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Title
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="titleid")
    private Title title;

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false, length=45)
    @NotEmpty(message="Please enter name.")
    private String name;
```

In Table 1, I want the titleid and name combination to be unique. I have added the constraint on the Database and on the Entity as such:

```
uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="user_unique", columnNames={"titleid", "name"})})
```

Now when I try to insert or update a record to be exactly as another record, I get the following exception, which is 100% correct.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry for key 'user_unique'
```

My question is how to handle it in Spring Boot? I am on the latest version of Spring Boot, Hibernate, etc. Is there an annotation I can place on the name column in Table 1 which will gracefully handle it and return a nice message or do I have to handle this in the exception? Or am doing this totally wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Paste your model class too.

Comment: what do you meant by how to handle it in springboot?

Comment: I added the part of the Entity class. This is not my exact code because it's way to big, this is just example code to simulate what I have done.

Comment: Spring Boot handles most database exception like a column which may not be empty by using @NotEmpty. But I cannot find anything which easily handles Unique Constraint records.